# Iframe in a react component couple of times

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I have my this div in react component.

```
<div className="panel-layout-card">
            <div className="d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center p-2 bg-light">
              <iframe sandbox="" title={stream?.title} className="w-100 h-90vh" src={url} />
            </div>
          </div>
```

Whenever I come to this component clicking on a button I have to click on back button two times to go back to the page from where I came. How can I resolve this?